# Как сделать отступ первой строки для GridView?

Tags: getview, android, gridview, java

Есть сетка (`GridView`). Хочу сделать для первой строки `left_margin = 120`, но не получается из-за того, что вьюха принимает `AbsListView.LayoutParams(в getView)` в котором margin-ов нет вообще.

Как это обойти?

Идея такая: в сетке первая строка сдвинуты(имеют отступ слева) на 120 пикселей, а все остальные строки сетки без сдвигов.

По-хорошему нужно сдвинуть хотя бы нулевой элемент. Но и это не получается.

Comment: А как вы хотите задать margin для одной строки? 
Лично я делал отступ заполняя пустотой  первые сколько то ячеек (и не вешал обработчиков соответственно, но там есть неприятный бонус в виде того, что видно при нажатии, что это ячейка).
Если честно трудно представить где именно сдвиг нужен? Может скажете, что вы реализуете, может мысли бы какие-то возникли

Comment: обновил вопрос.

Comment: Честно не знаю, только вот вариант с пустой ячейкой (или количество ячеек должно быть обязательно одинаковое в первой строке и остальных?)

Comment: В первую ячейку положить в хмл что-то с маржином?)

Comment: Да, и не хрена это не просто. Как оказалось.

Comment: @DroidAlex поделитесь как решили проблему